# Can I increase number of buckets after table creation in hive?

Tags: hive, bucketing

In hive, once the table is created with n buckets. Is their any way to increase number of buckets?

Answer (score 0):

Buckets are physical folders so we cant do it easily. You need to recreate the table with new structure.
step 1 - create a table with new structure.

```
CREATE TABLE  [db_name.]newtable (...)
[CLUSTERED BY (col_name, col_name, ...) INTO num_buckets BUCKETS;
```

step 2 - reload newtable from original.

```
insert into newtable select * from mytable;
```

step 3 - drop original table and rename new table to original.

```
drop table mytable;
alter table newtable rename to mytable;
```